# Changing Fields for Graduate School

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

During my undergraduate years I was interested in condensed matter theory and string theory and I was debating which topic to choose for my grad school application. I finally decided to go to string theory but during grad school application this year I got rejected from every single grad school I applied to. For the next cycle I am wondering if I should go to condensed matter theory. I plan to apply to the same schools (along with some new ones). Will the old schools frown upon the fact that I changed subfields for practical reasons? After all I do like condensed matter theory, just my other liking didn't work well.

Comment: How many places did you apply to? Are you sure that it was down to the topic, and not some other facet of your application? I don't think that condensed matter would be much less competitive than string theory.

Comment: Tbh nobody really cares about strings. There aren't any practical applications associated with it and so not much funding put into it. You will have an easier time in CMP since it's one of the few areas which has funding.

Comment: @FourierFlux Will future admissions committees frown upon this? Will they think that I am just changing subjects and conclude that I am not focused?